# Calendar API Only Shows Free/Busy

Tags: api, calendar

I am using the Calendar API and have successfully retrieved data from it. But, I am currently only getting free/busy information. If I change the public calendar sharing settings to "See all event details" for the public I can see all information. I don't want the public to see this information, but instead only the API user.

Is there a way to set it so only the API is given this detail information without making it public?

Comment: You haven't mentioned yet, but what programming language are you using, and is this a web application?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging into the API with an OAuth token?  Was that OAuth created with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly` scope or the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` scope?

Here are the API details on authorizing with Calendar - https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

Comment: Well, I don't remember and I can't seem to find where that would be in the API or key information. But, if I go to my calendar and change it to See all event details the API is given the information I'm looking for.

The only other way I can figure to do this is if I have an email address for the key/api so I can specifically grant permission to that 'person'.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't know what your use case is, but does the page you created require you to click a login button and log in with your Google account?  This is the only way to create the needed OAuth token as far as I can tell.  I did this to connect my Google Contacts with a server at home and had to actually log in with their federated login in a web browser.

Comment: Not currently. Right now it just loads and pulls the data from the calendar and never asks for any authentication (other than what is provided in the script). I tried adding the Client ID in the admin console but still no go. I also tried including the credentials email address as a way to define additional permissions but it still won't provide the details of the meeting, only that it's occurring and at what time.

Comment: I think you've discovered the problem.  Google's API isn't really designed for a no-operator scenario.  Someone must click, sign in, and grant permission to create the permissions.  As a service provider, this makes sense - the end user must "sign in with Google" to grant the permission to the service provider.  You are probably doing this for personal use, so you are both the service provider and the end user.  For me, that meant creating a sign-in page.  I went to that page, clicked Sign in and was asked if I wanted to grant permission to my own app.  The token can be refreshed indefinitely.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I'm not really sure where to go from here but I'll look into creating a one-time sign in page I guess.

Comment: I'd offer more, but I don't know the details of the project or even what structure or language we're talking about.  But this is where I started: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#overview